# Nonstandard spellings for dialects

Tags: orthography, dialects, contractions, eye-dialect

Are there standard ways of indicating dialect, as "I 'aven't," I asked 'is name," and especially "It couldn't 'a' 'appened."  Can "have" be indicated with just "a"?

Comment: Whatever style you use, if you're consistent with it, readers will adapt to it and will cease to be distracted by the gentle rainfall of apostrophes (on the one hand) or the appearance of a naked _a_ to stand for _have_ (on the other). If the original used lots of apostrophes, you might be inclined to retain them for historical authenticity; the only countervailing consideration is whether the presentation of so many apostrophes will discourage readers from sticking with the narrative long enough to get used to the style.

Answer (score 1):

It will depend on dialect, and probably even more so on its written history.

If it's a book oriented towards the majority of the English-speaking world (or expecting many non-native speakers to read it), the apostrophes become more important.

If the book is oriented towards people already familiar with the dialect in question, you are less likely to need an apostrophe every half word.

Basically, consider the audience, and what they'll be familiar with.  Any standard will be decided through tyranny of the masses and what other authors have done in the past that people consider to be of good form.

And don't forget another option: write with MSE spelling but dialectal syntax, and then add in the intended dialect, such as: “‘What are you saying?’ he asked, his voice thick with a central Alabamian accent”<sup>1</sup> to be read mentally by the reader as *W**h**at are ya sayin’?*.  That will let you effectively represent things (like the wh-w distinction in my example) that are difficult to otherwise show otherwise.

<sup>1. There are certainly more elegant ways to integrate this, but an elegant writer I'm not.</sup>

Comment: While waiting for answers, I found useful guidance in reading Joseph's dialogue in Emily Bronte's "Wuthering Heights." I'm copyediting a novel set in 1625; author has tried to approximate rough talk of sailors, but I want the reader to understand. Some findings: ha' = have; 'ems = them; o' = of; a right = all right; e'er = ever. @guifa: Am familiar w NE Alabama dialect and West Alabama dialect, but not central.